# How literals and constants are being interpreted and saved by the program

Tags: c++, save, constants, literals, extract

Since variables have to be defined by a data type i cannot understand why that doesn't apply to literals and const.
How can the program tell if it has to save the value of a const as an int or double etc.
And how is it able to use arithmetic operators to calculate for example the sum of two const.
I mean how does it extract the numeric value from 234 if it is saved as the sequence of three  (2, 3, 4) numbers. How can that number possibly have a value if it isnt first being converted by a data type. I mean when you type in those numbers aren't they saved as just another character. I mean i know I'm wrong but please tell me why.

Answer (score 0):

Literals do have types. For example,

- The type of `234` is `int`.
- The type of `23.4` is `double`.
- The type of `'a'` is `char`.
- The type of `"hello, world"` is `const char[13]`.

The types of literals can be modified with prefixes and suffixes. For example,

- The type of `234u` is `unsigned int`.
- The type of `23.4f` is `float`.
- The type of `L'a'` is `wchar_t`.
- The type of `L"hello, world"` is `const wchar_t[13]`.

C++11 adds additional kinds of built-in literals and also user-defined literals.

Every literal has a well-defined type. Of course, a literal like `234` is easily converted to *any* numeric type, which is why you can do `double x = 234;`. Still, `234` in this context has type `int`, as it always does, and not `double`.